# How do I install Redis Cache on Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-role, azure-redis-cache

I want to install Redis Cache on Azure virtual machine. Is there any documentation available for this?

Comment: Why do you prefer managing your own redis cache vs. the redis cache service?

Comment: to perform some development assignments as cost is more for redis cache service, my R&D is going to take time and need huge data operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you install redis cache on a non-Azure machine?  What are you thinking would be different about installing it on an Azure VM?

There are lots of how-to's out there:
http://freshclickmedia.co.uk/2013/09/installing-redis-on-windows/

> 1. Download the latest .exe package from https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads (choose the appropriate latest 32 or 64 bit version).
>
> 2. Running the exe will install Redis as a service and install the Redis client.

Comment: I have installed it using nuget package in my mvc application but in VM i need to use `redis-3.0.0.tar.gz` file